# Time complexity for recursive algorithm mapping digits to letters, phone keypad style

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, recurrence

The following code returns all possible letter sequences that a sequence of digits could represent, using a phone keypad to map digits to letters, as in the following image.

[image: phone keypad]

Here are some example inputs and outputs:

> Input: "2"
> Output: ["a","b","c"]
>
> Input: "23"
> Output: ["ad", "ae", "af", "bd", "be", "bf", "cd", "ce", "cf"]

If `n` is the number of digits in the input, and `k` is maximum number of characters mapped to an individual digit, what would be time complexity?

I have come up with the following recurrence relation (correct me if I am wrong): `T(n) = T(n-1) + k^(n-1) * k`

But I am not able to figure out the time complexity. Could someone help me  understand how to calculate the time complexity of this type of solution?

```
class Solution {
    public List<String> letterCombinations(String digits) {
        if(digits == null || digits.length() == 0) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        Map<Integer, List<Character>> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(2, Arrays.asList('a','b','c'));
        map.put(3, Arrays.asList('d','e','f'));
        map.put(4, Arrays.asList('g','h','i'));
        map.put(5, Arrays.asList('j','k','l'));
        map.put(6, Arrays.asList('m','n','o'));
        map.put(7, Arrays.asList('p','q','r','s'));
        map.put(8, Arrays.asList('t','u','v'));
        map.put(9, Arrays.asList('w','x','y','z'));
        
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        recurse(digits, result,"", map, 0);
        return result;
    }
    
    public void recurse(String digits, List<String> result, String temp, Map<Integer, List<Character>> map, int index) {
        if(index == digits.length()) {
            result.add(temp);
        } else {            
            Integer ch = Character.getNumericValue(digits.charAt(index));
            List<Character> chars = map.get(ch);
            for(int i=0; i < chars.size(); i++) {
                recurse(digits, result, temp + chars.get(i), map, index + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to find the time complexity for enumerative algorithms like this (where you gather all ways of doing something) is to think about how many outputs there are, and how long it takes to compute an output.

If you have `n` characters, each of which maps to `k` options, then the number of possible results is `k^n`. The complexity of your algorithm is therefore *at least* `k^n`, or `Omega(k^n)`, because `O(k^n)` outputs are enumerated.

We still need to consider how long it takes to compute each input. Notice that you're building a `String` of length `n` by adding one character at a time. Since `String`s are immutable, every time you add a character, an entirely new `String` must be created. The work involved to produce a `String` of length `n` by appending characters is `1 + 2 + ... + n = O(n^2)`.

Thankfully, the work done to create the result is the same for all results. Therefore, we can just multiply the number of results by the work for each result, to arrive at the final complexity `O(n^2 * k^n)`, or more specifically, `Theta(n^2 * k^n)`.

---

We can also obtain a recurrence relation as follows. Let `i` be the same as `index` in your code, which counts up from `0` to `n`. Let `j` be `n-i`, which means "the number of digits left to process".

We then have `T(j) = k*((i+1) + T(j-1)) = k*((n-j+1) + T(j-1))` and `T(0) = 1`. Your overall time complexity is given by `T(j)` where `j=n`.

Explanation: Suppose you have `j` digits left to process, which corresponds to a single call to `recurse`. We need to loop over `k` characters, and on every iteration of that loop, we do `i+1` work (to add a char to `temp`) as well as `T(j-1)` work (to recurse, having one fewer digit left to process).

If we "unroll" the recurrence, we find:

```
T(n) = k*(1 + T(n-1))
     = k*(1 + k*(2 + T(n-2)))
     = k*(1 + k*(2 + k*(3 + ... k*(n + 1)...)))
     = 1*k + 2*k^2 + 3*k^3 + ... + n*k^n + 1*k^n
```

Then we need to upper-bound and lower-bound this sum.

```
T(n) <= 1*k^n + 2*k^n + ... + n*k^n + 1*k^n
      = (1 + 2 + ... + n)*k^n + 1*k^n
      = O(n^2 * k^n)
```

A lower bound is trickier. Let `a` be any constant with `0 < a < 1`. Let `m = floor(a * n)`.

```
T(n) >= m*k^m + (m+1)*k^(m+1) + ... + n*k^n    (there are n-m+1 terms)
     >= (n-m+1) * m*k^m                        (replace each term with m*k^m)
      = (constant*n) * (a*n)*k^(a*n)
      = constant * n^2 * k^(a*n)
```

This means, for any constant `0 < a < 1`, we have `T(n) = Omega(n^2 * k^(a*n))`, so we can prove that our lower bound for `T(n)` is arbitrarily close to `Omega(n^2 * k^n)`.

Combined with the upper bound, we have shown that `T(n) = Theta(n^2 * k^n)`.

Comment: Since the OP doesn't seem to be familiar with Big-O, you could improve this by explaining that `k` should take the _largest_ value if it is not constant (making `k=4` here).

Comment: I think the OP does know about Big-O notation, because otherwise one wouldn't attempt to use a recurrence relation (which are typically taught after Big-O notation is introduced, as a way of computing Big-O).

Answer (score 0):

The complexity in Big-O notation is `O(4^n)`.

This is not *exactly* what you asked for - you asked for the time complexity - but Big-O is a common way of expressing that.

Note that I did not use `k` at all - this is because `k` varies depending on the exact composition of your input string, and Big-O takes the worst possible running time (which in your case is if all the digits mapped to four different letters).

If you want to use `k`, you could do this:

```
O(k1^n1 * k2^n2 * k3^n3 ...)
```

Where `k1` is a particular value of `k`, and `n1` is the number of digits in the input string that map to that value of `k`. In your example, there would only be `k1=3` and `k2=4`, since no other values of `k` are possible: `O(3^n1 * 4^n2)`

Comment: Not sure why you have to separate out `k` into `k1` and `k2`, you need to take the max of `k1` and `k2` which is exactly `k` as defined by OP. This is also incorrect because it doesn't account for the time taken to create each result.

Comment: @pkpnd Yes, I missed the cost of the string concatenation. I split it out because, as you can see from the code, `k` is not a constant, and has no meaningful value unless the maximum is taken (which is what I did - see the first line on my answer - although I got the notation wrong!). The rest of my answer is not Big-O, because it's looking at the actual case for a given input, which is admittedly not that useful, but the OP seemed to be looking for something along those lines.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion this is as easy as:

if `N = digits.length`, and `k = number of letters for this button`, then `k*N`, so `O(kN)`.

Comment: It's exponential, most definitely not O(kN)